# How to take in multiple strings as input in Flutter FormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a field in a form I am making in Flutter that needs to take in multiple separate strings. A user should also be able to remove one of the strings after it was input. For example, if the user types in "Flying", hits enter, then types "Carrot" my goal is to send the array ["Flying", "Carrot"] to the back-end with the other form data.

Is there any widget that allows for this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [textfield_tags](https://pub.dev/packages/textfield_tags) package. here i made example for you:

```
class FormTagExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormTagExampleState createState() => _FormTagExampleState();
}

class _FormTagExampleState extends State<FormTagExample> {
  List listTag = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFieldTags(
      tagsStyler: TagsStyler(
          tagTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          tagDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue[300],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          tagCancelIcon:
              Icon(Icons.cancel, size: 18.0, color: Colors.blue[900]),
          tagPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0)),
      textFieldStyler: TextFieldStyler(),
      onTag: (tag) {
        listTag.add(tag);
        print('tag: $listTag');
      },
      onDelete: (tag) {},
    );
  }
}
```

the result will look like this:
[image]

and you get an array:
[image]

Comment: This is a pretty great solution. Is there anyway that the strings can be made to have a space in them and not switch to a different tag?

Comment: After looking into it further I found the flutter_tags package which seems to work better for my use case. It allows me to put spaces in the input strings.